# SDL_KEYDOWN triggering twice

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I am following [lazy foo's tutorial](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/23_advanced_timers/index.php), however I realized every time I press press `s` or `p`, `SDL_KEYDOWN`triggers twice. How can this be fixed?

Here is the code snippet:

```
while(SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0) {
    if(e.type == SDL_QUIT) {
        quit = true;
    }
    else if(e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
        if(e.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_s) {
            if(timer.isStarted()) {
                timer.stop();
                printf("stop\n");
            }
            else {
                timer.start();
                printf("start\n");
            }
        }
        else if(e.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_p) {
            if(timer.isPaused()) {
                timer.unpause();
                printf("unpause\n");
            }
            else {
                timer.pause();
                printf("pause\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Pressing `s` once:

```
start
stop
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Check if `e.key.repeat` equals to `0` before handling the events.

---

SDL generates fake repeated keypresses if you hold a key long enough. This is used mostly for text input.

The original key press has `.repeat == 0`, and fake presses have `.repeat == 1`.

For convenience reasons probably (I'd argue that it's rather inconvenient), [since SDL 2.0.5](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/141689/sdl2-0-5-sdl-keydown-shows-two-identicle-presses-when-only-one-key-is-pressed/141692) the actual key press generates two events instead of one. One has `.repeat` set to `0`, and other (new) one has it set to `1`.